# Pycharm cannot import my modules while executing (the directory is present in the sources list and I can execute it just fine from the command line)

Tags: python, pycharm

It's throwing me this error:

```
/usr/bin/python -u /opt/pycharm-community-4.5.1/helpers/pydev/pydev_run_in_console.py 58137 38816 /path/to/my/module.py
/usr/lib/python/site-packages/IPython/external/path.py:32: DeprecationWarning: the md5 module is deprecated; use hashlib instead
  import sys, warnings, os, fnmatch, glob, shutil, codecs, md5
/usr/lib/python/site-packages/IPython/iplib.py:58: DeprecationWarning: the sets module is deprecated
  from sets import Set
Running /path/to/my/module.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/pycharm-community-4.5.1/helpers/pydev/pydev_run_in_console.py", line 69, in <module>
    globals = run_file(file, None, None)
  File "/opt/pycharm-community-4.5.1/helpers/pydev/pydev_run_in_console.py", line 29, in run_file
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "/path/to/my/module.py", line 13, in <module>
    import my.module.name
ImportError: No module named my.module.name

Process finished with exit code 1
Couldn't connect to console process.
```

If I run it on the BASH terminal, it's executing just fine. It was actually executing fine from PyCharm too, but I'm not sure what changed and I suddenly started seeing this happening. Also, it doesn't show any errors about the missing module in the editor, which suggests that at least the editor can see those packages in the path where it searches. PYTHONPATH also has this directory.

Comment: have you added _ _init_ _.py files to your module folders ?

Comment: Yes. That's the first thing I checked. The editor doesn't show any errors, and it works fine from the command line. I've added this info to my question now.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Removing PYTHONPATH from the environment variables for the run fixed the issue.

Steps to fix:

1. Run -> Run...
2. Edit Configurations
3. Select the configuration for the run that's affected
4. Click on button labeled `...` next to Environment Variables text field
5. Remove PYTHONPATH from the list of environment variables displayed there

I still don't understand what happened, but inspecting this variable before removing it showed the same list of paths added several times. That seemed very odd, so I removed this variable and tried, and it worked!